# How to best efficiently get multiple last_insert_ids

Tags: mysql, sql, last-insert-id

I have an SQL INSERT statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_tickets( tk_type, tk_qty) VALUES('typeValue1','qtyValue1'),('typeValue2', 'qtyvalue2'),('typeValue3', 'qtyValue3'); SET @lastId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

I realise that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will only get the `AUTO_INCREMENT` id for the first inserted from the list. There will be more lists. Is there a more efficient way of getting each of the `last_insert_ids` without repeating(with a PHP loop structure) the `INSERT` queries all over like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_tickets(tk_type, tk_qty) VALUES('typeValue1', 'qtyValue1'); 
SET @lastId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO my_tickets(tk_type, tk_qty) VALUES('typeValue2', 'qtyValue2'); 
SET @lastId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO my_tickets(tk_type, tk_qty) VALUES('typeValue3', 'qtyValue3'); 
SET @lastId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

I want to make other `INSERT` statements on another table based on these individual `last_insert_ids`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this. `last_insert_id()` reports only on the **LAST** tuple inserted. It has absolutely no capability of reporting on all IDs generated by a multi-values insert. If you need multiple last ids, you have to run multiple indepedent SINGLE values-set inserts.

Comment: If only there are no unique constraints in the table (which are passed in the query)